# Do murderers tend to return to the scene of the crime?

Tags: criminology

It is commonly heard that murderers (or other criminals) "always return to the scene of the crime".

Well, that's certainly false for *all* murderers. However, it is suggested that murderers do have a tendency to return to the scene of the crime.

Do a significant number of murderers pay another visit to the scene of the crime shortly after committing the crime?

Comment: Is this saying about all criminals or just murderers?

Comment: Do you have a notable source for this claim?

Comment: I'm following up with Vahid's comment. I believe that criminals that commit murders due to own psychological issues have a tendency to do so, bank robbers..? Probably not.

Comment: @VahidShirbisheh: Oh, yeah, as far as I can remember, it is murder. I will edit the question.

Comment: @EnergyNumbers: I'm sorry, I don't have a notable source. It is just commonly heard.

Comment: I think the whole plot point for "[Crime and Punishment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crime_and_Punishment)" can be used as a notable source.

Comment: I suspect that the answer is yes, but rather than because of any compulsion, people basically are creatures of habit and tend to go to the same places over an over.  Most murders are spur of the moment events so it is likely that they happen in places the murderer normally goes.  So chances are they will return to the vicinity of the crime at some point in the future.

Comment: @Chad: Oh yes, that makes sense. Although I guess we also have to consider those *planned murders*, where the murderer is most likely not going to kill in a place he frequents but rather do it somewhere away. The question would be: do they have a tendency to visit that place in the future?

Comment: @omega - You do not have a claim about that though.  As a whole most murders are not well planned(that or they are all really well planned so much as to confuse the cops into thinking otherwise.).

Comment: I understand the question is now limited to murderers, but I believe (no evidence) that it is even more applicable to arsonists.

Comment: on the crime shows they often make this claim about arsonists too.

Comment: Another reason could be that many people commit crimes in their own neighborhoods, so it is only natural for them to "return" at some people because they, you know, *live there*.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

My answer will only be partial, i.e. about serial killers.

The FBI "[Crime Classification Manual](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0787938858)" roughly divide serial killers in 3 categories: organized, disorganized and mixed.

While the organized serial killers are usually smart, plan their crimes beforehand, follow a precise and thorough ritual (and especially, use equipment they brought with them) and feel no regrets, the disorganized serial killer obey an uncontrollable urge, use weapons found on the scene and usually have regrets in the aftermath.

Because of afterthoughts, like regrets or fear to be discovered, the disorganized serial killers can return to the crime scene, hiding in the crowd. And an investigation method is to take pictures of the crowd on each crime scene, in order to search for persons appearing on several ones.

Quote of the indicated book, 2nd edition, page 220:

> Postoffense behavior exhibited may be a change in eating habits and
>   drinking habits (more alcohol consumption) and nervousness. He may
>   also have an inappropriate interest in the crime, for example, by
>   frequently engaging in conversation about it. Disorganized behavior
>   may be evident in victim selection, crime scene, and forensics due to
>   youthfulness, drug or alcohol impairment, external stressors (for
>   example, fear of discovery), or lack of criminal sophistication.

Comment: If "*Because of these regrets, the disorganized serial killers often return to the crime scene*" is from the manual it should be quoted.  If it is not from the manual then it will need to be backed up with some reference material.

Comment: Actually, my answer was incomplete. Regrets are not the only reason. I completed it and added a quote.

Comment: I like the addition of the quote I still think the claims about  the planning and the reasons for returning to the scene [need to be sourced](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/welcome-to-new-users).  If you can I think you will have a solid answer

Comment: Organized killers can also return to the scene, especially before they think it has been discovered, to re-live the event or revel in their "work." Some also will do things to the body, post mortem, at a later time, if they can.